# Division of Book File

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, datatable

file fragmentation algorithm

I have a problem. I'll find the size of the DataTable. 200 mb is equal to or smaller than a single XML document to be generated. 
Greater than 200, for example, the 500 MB will be created as 200,200,100. 
I understood that. in general, these,

Division of Book File

Of books to be generated (Y and K files) if the size to be divided is not exceeding 200 mbar. Each part as a result of the division of File Preparation Book and Book of the file to be sealed or signed, according to the steps to be created. Shredding should be aware of the following when performing;

· XBRL element which is gl-c: documentınfo data group is located in the glen-c: periodcoveredstart elements in the document to the e-book should be written the history of the first journal entry.

· XBRL element which is gl-c: documentınfo data group is located in the glen-c: periodcoveredend elements in the document to the e-book should be written the history of the last journal entry.

Below, for example, the period of January 2012 to be written for a notebook divided into three parts shown areas.

```
Part No. journal First Date Journal Last Date periodcoveredstart periodcoveredend

0001        2012-01-01      2012-01-10           2012-01-01          2012-01-10

0002        2012-01-11      2012-01-20           2012-01-11          2012-01-20

0003        2012-01-20      2012-01-31           2012-01-20          2012-01-31
```

DataTable can calculate registration records or ignore-case letters said. said that would be cumbersome. How else could it be?