# the fastest way to read the data from DataTable?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

How can I read the data in DataTable fastest way?

character by character

recording by recording

records * record size, they can not

I'm trying to find the size of DataTable

my question is linked with here

[Division of Book File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381075/division-of-book-file)

what else?

Comment: What means "recording by recording

records * record size, they can not"?

Comment: Finding size according to the the total number of records. 

number of records * a single record size

I want to find the size of a DataTable

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the table anyway, you can use  `LINQ-To-DataTable` to get short and readable code. Assuming that you have strings only:

```
var columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
int totalCharacterCount = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(r => columns.Sum(c => r.Field<string>(c).Length));
```

The inner `columns.Sum` calculates and sums the length of the strings in each column of one `DataRow`, the outer `Sum` calculates the total-sum, so adds all row's sum together.